# How do I stop displaying the subtotals in the columns?

Tags: powerbi

[image]

One of my clients want variance to be visible for "Account Category" > "Account group" level only. They don't want their users to see the variance at account level. The variance currently uses a measure

`Budget Amount to Actual Variance =  SUM ( 'GL Transactions - GLPOST'[Actual Amount] ) - SUM ( 'GL Transactions - GLPOST'[Budget Amount] )`

What is the best way to solve this problem?

I have tried using visualisation to change the colour of the font to white but that wouldn't work since alternate rows are grey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ISINSCOPE to identify what level you're at and adjust the calculation accordingly. For example assuming you've got an 'Account' dimension table you can use something like;

```
Variance = IF(ISINSCOPE(Accounts[Account]),BLANK(),[Budget Amount to Actual Variance])
```